# Get array descrption (not getData)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a form with Symfony and I want to get the description on the array and not the value, here is the code to explain:

```
$filieres = array
    (
        '1' => 'GI',
        '2' => 'GTR',
        '3' => 'GEII',
        '4' => 'GE',
        '5' => 'GINDUS',
        '6' => 'GC',
        '7' => 'STPI'
    );

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('filiere', 'choice', array('choices' => $filieres, 'attr' ...  ')))
....
```

To get the selected value in the form I use:

```
var_dump($form['filiere']->getData())
```

For example if someone selected "GTR I" get "2" with the code above, but what I want here is to get back "GTR" and not the value "2".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The value you're getting represents the index of your array. Just use it to check if the returned index exists in your array and display it. Returning the value from input is a normal behaviour of a form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the description values as both keys and values in your choices array:

```
$filieres = array
(
    'GI' => 'GI',
    'GTR' => 'GTR',
    'GEII' => 'GEII',
    'GE' => 'GE',
    'GINDUS' => 'GINDUS',
    'GC' => 'GC',
    'STPI' => 'STPI'
);
```

Comment: but the values that i want to put in database are those numbers !

Comment: Then why did you say for $form['filiere']->getData() "what i want here is to get back 'GTR' and not the value 2"? What I have suggested does what you've asked. Symfony uses form->getData() to map form data to the underlying data (entity or array) so if you want getData() to return something different it can only do so by also affecting what ends up in the DB.

Comment: Choice labels are never submitted and therefore never accessible from the form data. A sort of exception to this is the specialised choice field, 'entity', where symfony takes the selected entity id and finds the corresponding object instance under the covers. Then the controller can get whatever attribute was displayed as the choice description from the selected entity.

Comment: huuum, i see, because i used to find a function in c# to get the labels and not the value, so I assumed it may exist in symfony2 too, checked :D